# Change text of a link to this element's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update the text of a link with the text from the item clicked. I thought that `$(this).text();` would capture the element's text as a jQuery object, but nothing is happening.  I tried writing a fiddle but it gives me a post error. 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pitrik/hjd5fq18/)

```js
$(".country-label").on("click", function() {
    var updateCountry = $(this).text();
    console.log(updateCountry);
    $('#country-label').text(updateCountry);
    localStorage.setItem('CountryName', updateCountry);
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="country-label">Canada</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><label>Select your Country</label></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="country-label">United States</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="country-label">Australia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="country-label">France</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="country-label">Germany</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: ["The result of the .text() method is a ***string*** containing the combined text of all matched elements."](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Your code above is working fine?! https://jsfiddle.net/eoagyrez/

Comment: Your fiddle needs jQuery and you need to pass the `event` object into the callback. After that, it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/hjd5fq18/3/

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an actual project, I just forgot jquery in jsfiddle. The problem with that I didn't pass the event. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue(in your Fiddle) is that you're passing a string, `updateCountry`, instead of the variable. The jQuery should look like this:

```
$(".country-label").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var updateCountry = $(this).text();
    $('#country-label').text(updateCountry);
    console.log(updateCountry);
});
```

You also did not include jQuery in your Fiddle, I have updated it here:

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjd5fq18/1/)

Comment: Ugh, I keep forgetting that I have to add jquery to jsfiddle now. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's working in the fiddle but not locally, which means there's some type of conflict on my end. This still solved my problem, so marking this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(".country-label").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var updateCountry = $(this).text();

    $('#country-label').text(updateCountry);
    console.log(updateCountry);
});
```

And I change jsfiddle setting as:

[image]

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hjd5fq18/5/)